# show that the set of $x \in [0,1]$ whose decimal expansion does not have the digit 5, has Lebesgue measure zero

Tags: measure-theory

Some idea to do this exercise? I am completely lost.
I know that $\mathcal{L}(\emptyset) = 0$

But in this case obviously the set is not empty, so it must be coutable?

Please, help.

Comment: No, there are uncountable sets of measure $0$ like the [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set#Measure_and_probability)

Comment: @saulspatz and this question is an example